# RabbitTemplate receiveand convert method throws null pointer exception when I try to listen to a queue having json payload

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I need to queue my json payload in rabbitmq and receive the message from the queue. I can send the message tot he queue fine but when I try to retrieve the message from a topic exchange I get the null pointer exception. following line in onMessage method implementation throwing the null pointer exception.

`simpleMessage=(SimpleMessage) rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(qu);`

Can someone explain me how to do it or guide me to the link that has the solution

```java
@Component
public class RabbitListener implements me {

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplae;

    //@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {


    System.out.println("in listener");

        SimpleMessage simpleMessage= new SimpleMessage();
       // System.out.println("Received a new message = [" + new String(message.getBody().toString()) + "]");
        System.out.println("READY TO RECEIVE");
        String qu=message.getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue();

        System.out.println("que name  "+qu);
      //simpleMessage=(SimpleMessage) rabbitTemplae.receiveAndConvert("MyTestQueue");
        //System.out.println("rabbitMQ  RECEIVE MESSAGE "+  rabbitTemplae.receiveAndConvert("MyTestQueu", 100000));
        simpleMessage=(SimpleMessage) rabbitTemplae.receiveAndConvert(qu);

        //rabbitTemplae.receiveAndConvert
      // System.out.println( simpleMessage.getDescription());


    }
}
```

need to convert it back  to the following object from the queue

```java
public class SimpleMessage implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public SimpleMessage() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SimpleMessage{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: you should share NullPointer stack trace.

Comment: Yes; edit the question to show the stack trace. However, why are you creating a `SimpleMessage` and then overwriting it? (Not related to the question, it just looks odd). And why are you trying to receive a message from the same queue the delivery came from? Perhaps you have some basic mis-understanding?

Comment: yes from the same queue just like I can do it from rabbitMQ admin. There is no misunderstanding.